# Вставка swf в Mozilla с wmode="transparent"

Tags: firefox, flash, swf

Всем бобра.

Вот какое дело, вставляю с помощь [этого](https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/swfobject/2.2/swfobject.js)  swf-логотип. Вот так происходит вызов:

```
swfobject.embedSWF("<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/flash/slot.swf", "popular-slot", "334", "200", "10", null, null, { menu:"false", wmode:"transparent" });
```

Все хорошо, но в Mozilla через раз отображается логотип. Везде работает нормально - тут нет. Причем закономерности в этой проблеме тоже нет. Можно открыть страницу - и не будет swf. Можно открыть, обновить страницу несколько раз - и пропадет.

Пробовал:

- вставить без swfobject;
- менять в вызове swfobject все возможные параметры;
- применял к тому самому флешу CSS вот такой (position: relative;visibility: visible !important; z-index: 9999; zoom: 1;)

Замечено, что:

- флешка появляется, если прокрутить скролл;
- появляется, если убрать wmode=transparent, но он нужен, так как в самой флешке фон не прозрачный, а надо, чтобы был.

Проблема не с конкретной флешкой, а со всеми по сайту. Собственно вопрос: что такого происходит при работе wmode=transprent и что такое делает "дергание" скролла?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В общем, решил так:

- заменил swfobject на аналог, написанный на jquery (http://jquery.thewikies.com/swfobject/);
- добавил после инициализации вот так:

.

```
setTimeout(function(){
    $('#popular-slot object').css('position', 'relative');
}, 1000);
```